# Selenium - Unable to click button

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I'm unable to click a specific button in selenium. No error is thrown and it finds the element just fine, but I can't get it to click it.

**HTML**

```
<li id="btnTipsApp" class="navbutton appmenubutton">
  <a class="ls-icon-tips" onclick="setMainColumnMode(2);selectTab(4);selectNavButton('btnTipsApp');" href="#" title="Search Tips">&nbsp;
  </a>
</li>
```

**Relevant section of Python Code**

```
def userSearch():
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'btnTipsApp')))
    searchTipsButton = driver.find_element_by_class_name('ls-icon-tips')
    print (" tips button attribute: {0}".format(searchTipsButton.get_attribute('title')))
    searchTipsButton.click()
```

I'm using Selenium 3.0.2 and Firefox 51.0.1.

Comment: Check if there are more elements with class `ls-icon-tips`

Comment: Good thought, I thought that might have the been the issue myself, but there is only 1 class with that name.

Comment: It might be compatibility issue, try to downgrade firefox.

Comment: I will give that a try, but I should mention that I've been using the same version of selenium and firefox together for a few days now without issue. I've been able to click other buttons/links, fill in forms, and a few other functions no problem. This is the first time i've run into an issue.

Comment: Could you try `driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click()', searchTipsButton)`. Same result?

Comment: @Andersson A new result actually. It clicks the button now and the search screen opens, and then immediately closes again back to the home screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my own problem.

Solution was to wait for an element that took longer to load than the button I was trying to click. The button had loaded when I was clicking it, but something else it was relying on had not.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'bigItem')))
```